# Entity Framework 6 and Oracle: The table/view does not have a primary key defined. The Entity is read-only

Tags: oracle, entity-framework, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2019

I have an ASP.NET Core application that uses EF6 for dealing with a third-party application's database.

Everything is working as expected, but I'm unable to insert rows into a joining table.

I have two tables, `Users` and `Groups`, and a joining table `GroupUser` that identifies which users are members of which groups. `Users` has a PK of `UserId`, and `Groups` has a PK of `GroupId`.
`GroupUser` has only 3 columns: `GroupId`, `UserId` and another column (which is irrelevant for this post). The two foreign keys in this table identify a unique record.

Every time I try to insert into `GroupUser`, I get the inner exception

> The table/view does not have a primary key defined. The entity is read-only

The error is correct. There is no PK, but both of the FKs are marked as keys in the model. Shouldn't VS be able to use those as a PK somehow?

The inserts used to work as some point, but required some manual modification of the `.edmx` file as XML in order to work. Unfortunately, our version control records containing this modification have been lost (and I wasn't the one originally working on this).

I've looked at and tried about a dozen articles around this, but they generally have to do with views instead of tables, so don't seem applicable to my case. The ones that did seem applicable didn't solve the issue.

The only other clue I have for a solution is this comment I found in the code:

```
  // Important note: If you have updated the edmx file in the [redacted]
  // project and suddenly start having problems, the edmx file may need to be
  // edited as an xml file so that you can make changes necessary to make 
  // VS believe that the GroupUser table has a primary key. See revision #[redacted]
```

I'm able to insert into User and Group tables just fine, and as I've said, I don't have access to the revision log mentioned.

Edit: The database is for a third-party application, and unfortunately, it's not as simple as just modifying the table to add a PK. I wish it was. Problem would be solved. But I've been advised by the vendor not to make this change, as it may have unexpected consequences, and would void our support.

How can I 'trick' EF into thinking the table has a key? I'm also open to other workarounds. Modifying the DB structure is currently out of the question.

Comment: Every table needs a key.  So this table _should_ have a primary key or unique index.  And you just need to configure EF to treat it as a key.  It is possible to tell EF that the table has a key when it does not, but this can lead to unexpected behavior.

Comment: Why not just make `(UserId, GroupId)` the primary key of the join table - and get rid of all the problems? (possibly)

Comment: I'd prefer not to modify the DB if I can help it. It's for a third-party application.

Comment: @marc_s - This is a database for a third-party application, and modifying its structure might cause unexpected problems. I've already reached out to their support team about this, and they advised not to modify the structure of the DB, and that doing so would mean we lose their support.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft - As I've mentioned, this is a DB for a third-party application that I'm trying to integrate with. Modifying the DB to add a PK to that table is not supported by the application, and doing so will cause us to lose support for the application. How can I tell EF that there's a key when there's not? Not great practice, I know, but it might be my best bet.

Comment: You simply configure the key in the Fluent or Attribute-based configuration.  This is probably a composite key, so use the Fluent API as described here:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keys?tabs=data-annotations And obviously you won't be using Migrations.